# Lower bound on the integral of averaging operator.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the following I denote by $B(x,r)$ the ball centered at $x$ of radius $r$, and by $|B(x,r)|$ the measure of this ball.
I am trying to solve the following exercise.

**Question**

Let $f \geq 0, R \geq 0$ and $B_R$ a ball of radius $R$ in $\mathbb R^d$.
    Show that for every $0 < r< R$ we have
    $$
  \int_{B_R} f \leq C \int_{B_R} \left( \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} f \right) d x,
$$
    where $C$ is a constant **only depending on $d$**.

**Attempt**

When $f$ is bounded, using the **Lebesgue differentiation theorem**
I can show that there exists $R'$ such that for all $r \in (0, R')$
it holds
$$
  \int_{B_R} f \leq 
2 \int_{B_R} \left( \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} f \right) d x.
$$
So it remains to prove the inequality when $r \in (R', R)$ and also generalize it for unbounded functions $f$.  I am not sure how to proceed
from this